# E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating a simple soundboard to play sounds when a user clicks a button. Problem is, if the button is pressed enough ( usually around 10 times ) it will eventually stop playing and show the error `E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)`
what am I doing wrong? My code that plays the sound:

```
private void playSound(int soundID){
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,soundID);
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mp.start();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have you implemented play and pause functionality and also add button click

Comment: Yes i have added button click this is just a base method i can use on every button. And i dont know what play and pause functionality is, so i dont think i implemented it.

Comment: ok.. in onPrepared add  if (mp != null)  mp.start();

Answer (score 1):

You should use Soundpool. It's created exactly for playing short sound effects. And it's much simpler to use than MediaPlayer. MediaPlayer should only be used for playing regular/large music.

See here for example:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidMedia/article.html#tutorial-play-sounds-via-soundpool

Note: No need to use onTouch as in the example, you can just use onClick for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Reason: "W/Choreographer: (let say) Frame time is 0.239384 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase."
i.e, there is a much gap between timestamps.
This problem can be removed by using setOnCompletionListener() within your OnClick() method like: `

```
            @Overrid
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            // Get the {@link Word} object at the given position the user clicked on
            Word word = words.get(position);

            Log.v("NumbersActivity","Current word: "+word);

            // Create and setup the {@link MediaPlayer} for the audio resource associated with the current word
            MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(NumbersActivity.this, word.getAudioResourceId());

            // Start the audio file
            mMediaPlayer.start();

           // Keep timeStamp sync
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mMediaPlayer.release();
                }
            });
        }
```

`

Comment: mMediaPlayer.release() is what i need to avoid error (1, -19)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void playSound(int soundID){
  final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,soundID);
  mp.start();
  mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mp.release();
        }
  });
}
```

Comment: You should call mp.start() **after** you call mp. setOnCompletionListener(...). It is possible that the MediaPlayer will complete before the OnCompletionListener has been set.