# I keep getting Error (1,-19) when trying to run an audio file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to play a sound in android using the MediaPlayer, but I keep getting the same error.

> D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer   E/MediaPlayer: error
>   (1, -19)
>
> E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)

This is my only code so far.

```
 public void playSound(View view){

        MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clap);

        mPlayer.start();
    }
```

Comment: are you unable to play the sound even once ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539408/e-mediaplayer-error-1-19

Comment: Yeah, I'm unable to play the sound even once. And I'll check that other question out. Thanks