# How do I resolve MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I am playing media player in non activity class, facing an issue when frequently playing an audio clip, the media player is throwing MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19). Once this error occured, the media player is not playing at all. I have gone through some of the [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539408/e-mediaplayer-error-1-19), but i didn't get any solution. Any help would be appeciated.

```
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                delayInExecution = false;
                if (!mLeftOpen && !mRightOpen) {
                    System.out.println("Eyes are closed man....");
                    try {
                        if (!player.isPlaying()) {
                            player = MediaPlayer.create(EyeDetectionApplication.getInstance(), R.raw.beep);
                            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                            player.setLooping(false);
                            player.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {

                                    System.out.println("setOnErrorListener ....");
                                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(EyeDetectionApplication.getInstance(), R.raw.beep);
                                    mediaPlayer1.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                    mediaPlayer1.setLooping(false);
                                    mediaPlayer1.start();
                                    player = mediaPlayer;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            player.start();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception came....");
                        player = MediaPlayer.create(EyeDetectionApplication.getInstance(), R.raw.beep);
                        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        //   player.setOnPreparedListener(EyeDetectionApplication.getInstance());
                        player.setLooping(false);
                        player.start();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mLeftOpen && mRightOpen && player.isPlaying()) {
                        player.release();
                    }
                }

            }
        }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 2):

add OnCompletionListener in your media player and release it.

```
player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.release();
};
});
```

move this line from the handler inside

```
 player = MediaPlayer.create(EyeDetectionApplication.getInstance(), R.raw.beep);
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {//other code
        }
         })
```

Comment: Thank you.. I will check

Comment: don't create mediaplayer  inside thread ..move it  out of thread  player = MediaPlayer.create(EyeDetectionApplication.getInstance(), R.raw.beep);

Comment: Moving the initialization code out of thread did the trick. Thank you

Comment: I am trying but its not upvoting. I don't have enough points(15) to accept the answere i guess. sorry